# Toggle nav menu option on ng- click

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to build simple toggle menu functionality for menu dropdown. I have pick up some code from the on of stack post but its more relevant to tab functionality.

So how can we get this done. And is there will be any issue if I use jquery for this purpose.

http://jsfiddle.net/3G7Kd/107/

```
<div ng-app='app' class="filters_ct" ng-controller="selectFilter">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{sel: $index == selected}">
            <span class="filters_ct_status"></span>
            {{filter.name}}

            <ul class="subul" ng-if=filter.lists.length>
                <li ng-repeat="list in filter.lists">
                    {{list}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 

app.controller('selectFilter', function($scope) {

    $scope.filters = [
            {
                "name": "service",
                'lists': ['service a','service b','service c','service d']
            },
            {
                'name': "about us",
                'lists': ['about us a','about us b','about us c','about us d']
            },
            {
                'name': "product",
                'lists': ['product a','product b','product c','product d']
            },
            {
                'name': "more",
                'lists': ['more a','more b','more c','more d']
            }
        ];
    $scope.selected = 0;

    $scope.select= function(index) {
       $scope.selected = index; 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you just want to change `ng-click` with `ng-mouseover`:

```
ng-mouseover="select($index)"
```

I also added `ng-mouseleave` to remove any selection when you leave the nav element

If you need the click and you want the toggle click (show/hide) you have to change the `$scope.select` to:

```
$scope.select= function(index) {
   if ($scope.selected === index) 
       $scope.selected = null
   else
       $scope.selected = index; 
};
```

toggle click [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/3G7Kd/111/)

Mouseover [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/3G7Kd/109/)

Comment: So what's the problem with your code? It works with click

Comment: It should hide the menu when click again

Comment: that exactly what I want, lot of thanks michelem, Just one thing wanted to know. is jquery recommended with angular ?

Comment: That's a question too broad, as stated in the Angular FAQ you can use it but I prefer to use an Angular alternative instead. "Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite." https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq